# Basic Java Array and For Loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, random

I am taking a Java class and have read the same explanation over and over and I just want to make sure I am understanding it correctly.

The example in the class they provide is a dice rolling game and they want to see the frequency of rolls per number.

The code snippet that I am uncertain on is this:

```
for(int roll = 1; roll < 1000; roll++){
    ++freq[1+rand.nextInt(6)];
}
```

I understand this part: `1+rand.nextInt(6)`

But I don't understand this part: `++freq` and how it tallys the results

I am understanding this as (with the example I rolled a 4):

```
for(int roll = 1; roll < 1000; roll++){
    ++freq[4];
    //all indexes in freq are == 0 to start
    //freq[4] is index 4 in the array. It was 0 but is now == to 1
    //freq[0], freq[1], freq[2], freq[3], freq[5], and freq[6] are all still == to 0
}

for(int roll = 1; roll < 1000; roll++){
    ++freq[6];
    //freq[6] is index 6 in the array. It was 0 but is now == to 1
    //freq[0], freq[1], freq[2], freq[3], and freq[5] are all still == to 0
    //freq[4] and freq[6] are both == to 1
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: `++freq[4]` is short for  `freq[4] = freq[4] + 1`

Comment: For the record, `++freq[1+rand.nextInt(6)];` is rather unclear code. Unless you are developing on a 2 inch screen or are penalised for writing more lines of code, it is much clearer to write it as a variable `int roll = 1 + rand.nextInt(6);` and an increment `++freq[roll];`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int[] freq = new int[7];

    for(int roll = 1; roll < 1000; roll++){
        ++freq[1+rand.nextInt(6)];
    }
```

In the above code `rand.nextInt(6)` returns a value from 0 to 5 which is used to access the relevant integer value of the array `freq`

`++freq` part increases the accessed integer value by 1.

Example: 
 if `rand.nextInt(6)` returns `2`,

```
freq[1 + 2] = freq[1 + 2] + 1;
```

However, from `1 + rand.nextInt(6)`, 0 is never produced. Therefore, the first element of `freq` array should be ignored.

`freq[n]` will give you the frequency of the `nth` face.

Comment: this was a super helpful breakdown. Thank you!!